# getting collection referance from firebase undefined is not an object (evaluating 'parentDoc.id')

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from "@firebase/firestore"

export async function getParentId(collectionPath) {
  const collectionRef = collection(db, collectionPath);
  try {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collectionRef);
    const parentDoc = querySnapshot.parent;
    return parentDoc.id;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error getting parent ID:", error);
    return null;
  }
}
```

using it in another component

```
import { getParentId } from '../Firebase-Config'
... .
const parentId = getParentId("users");
console.log('getParentIdgetParentId',parentId)
```

Error

```
Error getting parent ID: [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'parentDoc.id')]
 LOG  getParentIdgetParentId {"_A": null, "_x": 0, "_y": 0, "_z": null}
```

Hello, I am trying to the get the collection referance(perant Id) from firestore so I can integrate it with the the realtime database

Comment: [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.querysnapshot.md#querysnapshot_class) does not have a `parent` property. What documentation are you looking at?

Comment: _"I am trying to the get the collection referance"_... don't you already have that in `collectionRef`?

Comment: @Phil firebase generates a unique key for every parent object in the collection, for example 
VvQVwVen2NwoThkV5DIY, so I am trying to get this key

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return the ID of the collection that these documents come from, you don't need to access the database at all and can instead just return:

```
return collectionRef.id;
```

---

If you want to show the document IDs of the documents in the `collectionPath` collection:

```
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collectionRef);
querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.id);
});
```

If you want to return a value, you'll have to decide of which document or if you want to return all of them.

---